# Find Polynomial of order 10 for $f(x)=sin(x)$ near x=0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

My work so far :

[image: Calculations]

I presume the answer should look more like a summation?

Thanks!

Comment: Check these out http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf It has the answers to your question and gives a feel for other taylor series

Comment: Yes, you end up with $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}$.

Comment: Are the "x" not replaced by 0 in the answer?

Comment: Jester-- No don't replace $x$ since you want approximation *near* zero.

Comment: Then does $sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}$ or is it ≈ to it? I guess it's equal as long as we don't give any numbers inside the variable x?

Answer (score 4):

Since the expansion of $\sin(x)$ has only odd powers of $x$, the even powers of $x$ have coefficients of $0$.

Thus, you are correct in that the $10$th power polynomial *approximation* of $\sin(x)$ centered around $x=0\quad$ is $\quad x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}$.

However this is only an approximation as $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

So, $\sin(x)$ can be represented by a polynomial above of infinite degree.

Note: With the $10$th degree approximation, we have $\sin(\pi/2)\approx1.000003542\cdot\cdot\cdot$

which is a fairly good approximation for relatively small $x$ but blows up for large $x$

For example, $\sin(100\pi)\approx8.2086\cdot 10^{16}\neq0$ which is obviously incorrect.